# Hide Storybook "new version is available" popup?

Tags: storybook

Whenever I start Storybook on localhost, I get this:
[image]
"Storybook [version] is available!" popup

This is particularly annoying on mobile as it takes up like 10% of the vertical space, and you need to re-close this popup everytime you restart the dev server

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your Storybook version is at least [**5.3.0**](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/releases/tag/v5.3.0-alpha.27)
Run storybook using:

```sh
start-storybook --no-version-updates
```

or in package.json

```json
"scripts": {
  "storybook": "start-storybook --no-version-updates"
}
```

More info:

- [Announcement post on Storybook GitHub](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6194#issuecomment-545966680)

Comment: FYI on the other hand `build-storybook --no-version-updates` is invalid. I'm not sure since I hadn't deployed my storybook anywhere yet, but I suspect the "new version available update" doesn't appear after you deploy build-storybook to a live site?